# Best Practice: How to realize a browsergame "building system"?

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing a browser game and stuck on a "theory problem".
I want to make the user to "level" specific buildings to gain better stats.

Example:

- Coal Mine: Lvl 1  (If user clicks on "upgrade" it will upgrade after X hours to lvl2 and so on)

Now my question is, **whats the best solution to handle it in the mysql database**?
What table setup's would you prefer and how to mange the "lvling" thing?

Would it be good to make a table called "buildings" and another one with "user_buildings" where a link to "buildings" is with actual level? 
Or are there better solutions?

Please help me with a good brainstorming :)

Comment: S.O is not your brainstorming department. "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: i do not want a "brainstorm" itself i want an advice for best practice on realizing it. i saw alot of "best practice" design pattern questions. i think asking this question is legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `buildings` table I would keep the buildings "definition" like hours needed to upgrade from lvl 1 to2 is X, from 2 to 3 is Y...

in `user_buildings` I would keep the users curent building, like: Coal Mine, located apt partition of map z, built started at u, current level u...

Answer (score 0):

Im making a Browsergame and Just finished the building System for the Resources and I made something that Adds a Timestamp to A Database and process / upgrade the Building AFTER the user logges in, using Real-Time Handling..

I'm Using A simple logic script that calculates the time depending on Server Speed and Bulding LVL.